# Find and replace using regular expressions in visual studio?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace

I have many function **DS_Anything Result[]**, now i want to Replace all to **List<DS_Anything Result>**

```
 Task<ResultCustomModel<DS_GetListMaterialNoMappingResult[]>> ListMaterialNoMapping(SearchlstMaterialInput input);
 Task<ResultCustomModel<DS_GetListShippingToSlittingResult[]>> GetListShippingToSlitting(ListShippingSearch input);
 Task<ResultCustomModel<DS_GetFormFinishWOLineResult[]>> GetDataEACTimeDownAndNG ( int eAContainerId, int userId );
```

And I expect

```
 Task<ResultCustomModel<List<DS_GetListMaterialNoMappingResult>>> ListMaterialNoMapping(SearchlstMaterialInput input);
 Task<ResultCustomModel<List<DS_GetListShippingToSlittingResult>>> GetListShippingToSlitting(ListShippingSearch input);
 Task<ResultCustomModel<List<DS_GetFormFinishWOLineResult>>> GetDataEACTimeDownAndNG ( int eAContainerId, int userId );
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Do back up your project / be using version control before you attempt any such changes though.

Comment: How to replace it with Regex, i search all answer in stackoverflow but not found

Comment: The [find and replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhOyB.png) dialog allows you to use regular expressions. Then, as always, youc an use $1, $2, etc. as the standins for your capture groups.

Comment: Look this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find: `DS_(.*)Result\[\]`

Replace: `List<DS_$1Result>`

Comment: @LongHoàngNguyễn it seems as though you were aware that regular expressions were supported in the find and replace all dialog. So, for the sake of me understanding how this answer helped you - was it that you weren't aware of these "standin" (output) notions for the capture groups were supported?

Comment: and to be clear, @LongHoàngNguyễn. I'm not familiar with "standin" term (hence the quotes) that was used in the question comments.. I think it's just "substitution pattern" that is using capture groups

Comment: @BrettCaswell I called them "stand-ins" because my brain couldn't conjure up the correct term at the time of my comment on the question. :D I expect you're correct.

Comment: @Llama I think it works.. so we should add it to the urban dictionary and make it somewhat officially defined to mean just that :D